# Is it normal that Ubuntu takes more than 2 hours in the partition process?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I have an Envy14 and I decided to install ubuntu 12.10. With the instalation manager I configured the partitions that will work as root, /home and swap. But it has been almost two and a half hours and ubuntu is still stock on that process. Is that normal? I gave ubuntu 200 Gb and the total of the hard drive is 640GB.

Comment: no definitely not normal.

Comment: I am not sure if the ubuntu 12.10 installer allows to resize other partition to make room for those used for the install. If this was the case... I can imagine that resizing a NTFS volume can for instance take some time. if there was not such a thing done/possible... then it agree witht the others.. it is not normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not normal. Normal is taking 1-5 minutes. You should make sure your installation media is good and start again. If you get the same problem twice you should go into the bios and turn off as many extra features as you can: I'm thinking touchpad and switchable graphics. If you're overwriting windows 8 your probably having a problem with secure boot. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly it is not normal. Try another media or whether possible, a USB stick, which is quicker as well.

For instance, I've just finished the installation of my Ubuntu (using it right now) and created / resized some partitions on a 1TB disk. Even formatting the partitions was pretty quick, took just few seconds.

If it still taking too long, try booting with a live distro in order to check the disk.

Comment: Ok, if you have 1TB disk and you say that it does not take too long then something went wrong. But anyway I started the process for a second time and it is all ok now: I've got Ubuntu 12.10 now instaled, thank you for answering :)